# How to install and import Bulma-extensions individually(eg., bulma-tooltip). Where should we do the imports for proper functioning

Tags: css, sass, bulma

```
<div class="column">
  <button class="button is-primary has-tooltip-multiline" data-tooltip="Tooltip with a long Text. So we use has-tooltip-multiline modifier to force multiline display.">Multiline Tooltip</button>
</div>
```

**Under _sass/main.scss:**

```
@import "../node_modules/bulma/bulma";

@import "bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass";
@import "bulma/sass/grid/columns.sass";

@import 'bulma';
@import '~bulma-tooltip';
```

I added the last two lines. Don't know if they are correct.

Also any suggestions for bulma-timeline..

I have installed it but don't know where to import for its functioning. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Bulma extensions, you can install the extension like that :

```
npm install bulma-tooltip
```

Then in the scss file where you import bulma you need to import the extension **after** the importation of Bulma.
For exemple, if your path to bulma is

```
@import "../node_modules/bulma/bulma.saas";
```

the bulma-tooltip package should be imported as below :

```
// Import the complete extension
@import '../node_modules/bulma-tooltip/src/sass/index.sass';
```

OR

```
// Import only what you need from the extension
@import '../node_modules/bulma-tooltip/src/sass/_animation.sass';
@import '../node_modules/bulma-tooltip/src/sass/_responsiveness.sass';
```

So the order in your scss file should be:

1) Customizing sass variables

2) Importing Bulma

3) Importing Bulma extensions

Answer (score -1):

The order should be like below, you won't need to import full module

```
// Update Bulma's global variables
$family-sans-serif: "Nunito", sans-serif;
$grey-dark: $brown;
$grey-light: $beige-light;
$primary: $purple;
$link: $pink;
$widescreen-enabled: false;
$fullhd-enabled: false;

// Update some of Bulma's component variables
$body-background-color: $beige-lighter;
$control-border-width: 2px;
$input-border-color: transparent;
$input-shadow: none;

// Import only what you need from Bulma
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/base/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/elements/button.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/elements/container.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/elements/title.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/form/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/components/navbar.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/layout/hero.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/layout/section.sass";
```

Comment: I tried but still couldn't get the desired result @bews99

Comment: where you add these imports?\

Comment: under _sass/main.scss. Some of them were already commented so had to uncomment them

Comment: what is the preprocessor you are using to convert sass?

Comment: @bews99 The order you mentioned is the one provide in the docs for bulma, for extensions the importation is explained in another place.